# Quotient of affine space by finite subgroup of SL(V) is Gorenstein

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

I am looking for a proof of the following fact:

If $G$ is a finite subgroup of $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ acting on $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$, then the resulting quotient scheme is Gorenstein.

Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, the canonical sheaf being a line bundle is not enough for being Gorenstein. E.g., a cone over an abelian surface has a trivial canonical sheaf, but it is not Gorenstein, because it is not Cohen-Macaluay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to show that the quotient scheme $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}/G$ is Gorenstein.

A proof can be made along the following line. Since $G \subset SL_n(\mathbb{C})$, the canonical bundle of $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ is $G$-equivariant and satisfy the following : for all $x \in \mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ which is fixed by some subgroup $H \subset G$, the group $H$ acts trivially on $\omega_{\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}} \otimes \mathbb{C}(x)$. Hence, by a classical criterion for descent, there is a line bundle $L$ on $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}/G$ such that $\omega_{\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}} = \pi^*L$, where $\pi : X \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}/G$ is the quotient map.

Now we know that $\omega_{\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}}$ and that $\pi_*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}})^G = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}/G}$. Using Grothendieck-Serre duality for the projective morphism $\pi$, it's easy to see that $\pi_*(\omega_{\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}})^G$ is a (up to a shift) a dualizing object on $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}/G$. Using the projection formula and the equality $\omega_{\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}} = \pi^*L$, one finds that $L$ is a dualizing object (up to a shift) on $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}/G$. Hence $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}/G$ is Gorenstein.

Comment: Could you explain how to conclude in your proof that $L$ has finite injective dimension (which is one of the requirements of being a dualizing object)?

Comment: If you worry that my proof could also be phrased in positive characteristic (while it is well-known that the result is false in positive characteristic) the issue is not there. The descent lemma, I am referring to uses the Reynolds operator, so it does't work in positive charcateristic.

Comment: As far as the finite injective dimension is concerned, we know that $L$ is a line bundle which is a dualizing object on $A_{\mathbb{C}^{n}/G$, so it has finite injective dimension.

Comment: You are using a circular argument. Having finite injective dimension is a requirement for being a dualizing object. So if you want to play it this way, then my question is, how do you know that $L$ is a dualizing object? More to the point, $L$ having finite injective dimension is equivalent to $\mathscr O$ having finite injective dimension which is equivalent to being Gorenstein. The fact that L satisfies the duality part of the definition (see 3) in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A7B) is trivial. The real question is 1), which you seem to suggest follows from 3), but that's not true.

Comment: @SándorKovács I don't think my argument is circular, I guess you just don't understand it. Let me give you some again some extra details. Let $F \in D^b(V/G)$, we have $\mathrm{R} \mathcal{H}om_{V/G}(F, \mathcal{R} \pi_{*}^{G} \mathcal{O}_{V}[n]) = \mathcal{R} \pi_*^{G} \mathrm{R} \mathcal{H}om_{V}^{G}(\mathrm{L} \pi^*F, \mathcal{O}_{V}[n])$, by the $G$-equivariant projection formula. Since $\omega_{V}$ is $G$-equivariantly locally trivial, the object $\mathcal{O}_{V}[n]$ is a $G$-equivariant dualizing object on $V$ (continued...)

Comment: Assume that $\mathrm{L} \pi^* F$ is bounded above in $D^{qc}(V)$. Then by the $G$-equivariant version of Serre duality on $V$, we have $\mathcal{R} \sigma_* \mathcal{R} \pi_*^{G} \mathrm{R} \mathcal{H}om_{V}^{G}(\mathrm{L} \pi^* F, \mathcal{O}_{V}[n]) = (\mathcal{R} \sigma_* \mathcal{R} \pi_*^{G} \mathrm{R}\mathcal{H}om_{V}^{G}(\mathcal{O}_V, \mathrm{L} \pi^* F))^*$, where $\sigma : V/G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Since we have $\mathrm{R} \mathcal{H}om_{V/G}^{G}(\mathcal{O}_{V}, \mathrm{L} \pi^*L) = \mathrm{L} \pi^* L$, we deduce that $\mathcal{R} \sigma_* \mathcal{H}om_{V/G}(F, \mathcal{R} \pi_*^{G} O_{V}[n]) = (\mathcal{R} \sigma_* (F \otimes \mathcal{R} \pi_*^{G} O_{V}[n]))^*$. As $\mathcal{R} \pi_*^{G} \mathcal{O}_{V} = \mathcal{O}_{V/G}$, we finally get $\mathcal{R} \sigma_* \mathcal{H}om_{V/G}(F, \mathcal{R} \pi_*^{G} O_{V}[n]) = (\mathcal{R} \sigma_* F)^*$, for all $F \in D^{b}(V/G)$ such that $\pi^* F$ is bounded above in $D^{qc}(V)$.

Comment: This shows that $\mathcal{O}_{V/G}[n]$ is a **dualizing object** on $V/G$. In particular, if you take $F =\mathcal{O}_{0}$ (structure sheaf of the point $0 \in V/G$), we get $\mathrm{Ext}^{k}(\mathcal{O}_{0}, \mathcal{O}_{V/G}) = 0$, except for $k =n$, where  $\mathrm{Ext}^{k}(\mathcal{O}_{0}, \mathcal{O}_{V/G}) = \mathbb{C}^*$. Proving, as a byproduct, that $\mathcal{O}_{V/G}$ has finite injective dimension.

Answer (score 6):

1. By the [Hochster-Roberts Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochster%E2%80%93Roberts_theorem) it is Cohen-Macaulay
2. The canonical sheaf of $\mathbb A^n$ is $G$-invariant (because the elements of $G$ have det=1) and hence it descends to the canonical sheaf of the quotient, which is then a line bundle.